# Path-Based Vulnerability: Threat file created when enable CDN to my domain

Tags: security, gzip, cdn

when I enable CDN to my https Domain, the following file created path-based vulnerability threat file automatically

```
[<https://mywebsite.com/cdn-cgi/ping.gz>][1]
```

How do i remove this Unwanted File from my domain?